# Multisignature Demographics

Tags: multi-signature

Has there been any demographic analysis of multisignature operations?

If so, who's using them?  Is it true that multisignature operations are limited mostly to exchanges?

Answer (score 1):

This article from coindesk may answer some of your questions although it is almost a year old now http://www.coindesk.com/year-multisig-so-far/

There's no information attached in multisig transactions to tell us what it is being used for so you can only guess. There are not any exchanges that uses multisig for any customer facing applications. There are however many online wallets, such as the one offered by Coinbase or Greenaddress , that uses multisig for better security.

Comment: Can you provide a link for the Coinbase and Greenaddress proofs?  Thank you in advance.